# How to fill a one-dimensional array grid with various blocks

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, grid

I have a grid stored in a one-dimensional array. The grid can be of variable size. I now have different blocks (2x2,2x3,2x4,3x3,3x4,3x5, 4x4 and so forth).

How do I fill the grid in now? It can have unused spaces left in the end but what is the fastest way here without looping through the array over and over trying out sizes?

For instance with this 5x5 grid.

```
var g1 = [
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
]
```

Comment: How are you representing the blocks to fill the grid, and what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [backtracking algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) to solve this type of problem:

```
function process(var blockstate) {
    if(gridIsFullOfBlocks(blockstate))
         return true;
    if(canPlaceBlock(blockstate)) {
         blockstate = placeLargestBlock(blockstate);
         return process(blockstate);
    }
    return false;
}

function fillBlocks(int size) {
    var blockstate = new Array(size);
    if(process(blockstate))
        displayBlockstate(blockstate);
    else
        displayError(blockstate);
}
```